# bitmaps not looking smooth

Tags: gdi+, antialiasing

I am loading raster files (png) in my viewer application. When I view these files in an application such as IrfanView everything looks very smooth. Somehow the antialiasing settings in my viewer application do not work: lines have very jagged edges.

I do set the SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias. I've tried different combinations of the various settings but to no avail.

Is GDI+ not capable of this like IrfanView is?

Answer (score 0):

bitmaps aren't antialiased, text and vector images are - perhaps your problem is that the images are being stretched and resized

Comment: They are resized when zooming in or out. But still the quality of the image when viewed using IrfanView or even the Windows Picture and Fax viewer is far better. A line is smooth at all zoom levels, almost like a vector, and in my gdi+ app you can see the pixels. Jagged edges and when you zoom out very far only a few dots remain of the line.